# Missing data change events

Tags: opc-ua

I have a data source delivering values that I want to expose through an OPCUA server. The data source is event-driven and can deliver multiples values for one variable in a single notification. I want to configure an OPCUA client to receive all values regardless of the period (just no losses).

**What I tried:**

*Simulation*

I have variable who ramps from 1 to 10 every 100ms. The data source emits *n* events containing *m* values changes. When the server receives events, he writes the corresponding OPCUA node with all the changes.

*Client configuration*

The client has a subcription with a publishInterval of 1000 ms, a monitored item with a queue size of 100 and a samplingInterval of 0 ms. The server is sending back a revisedSamplingInterval of 50ms.

*Expected results*

I want to receive all data change from 1 to 10.

*Results*

I'm missing some values. I think it's because I write the OPCUA node with all value when I receive them and the server can't sample it but I'm not sure.

**Questions**

It is possible to achieve this with opcua ?
Do I need a special treatment on the server ? Is it normalized or is it implementation details ?
Do I need other settings for the client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the client configuration was fine but the server didn't support a null sampling interval. After adding 0 to the list of available sampling interval, the server sends back a revisedSamplingInterval of 0 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You’re doing the right thing in the client by creating a MonitoredItem with a larger queue size but unfortunately whether or not the the rest of this works is going to be an implementation detail of the server and how it implements sampling and subscriptions.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this ? Should I use events or something else ?